# Why is the number of Sylow 2 subgroups of simple group with order 60 not able to be 1 or 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I want to show that a simple group of order 60 is isomorphic to $A_5$. In the process, I am stuck at the part in which I have to show that the number of Sylow 2 subgroups (whose orders are 4) cannot be 1 or 3; it therefore has to be 5 or 15.

I searched for all contents of Hungerford chapter 2, but am not able to prove this fact... Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup, then it is normal.

If there are $r$ of them, then $G$ acts by conjugation transitively
on the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups. If $G$ is simple, this action
must be faithful, and $G$ is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of $S_r$.

Comment: @Bernard Here, an obvious typo for simple ...

Comment: I see. Since  you fixed it, I'll remove my comment.

Comment: Could you explain what faithful means?

Comment: And how does this forbid the number 3?

Comment: An action is faithful when its kernel is trivial @Keith